# Diference between myData as string, (string) myData and Convert.ToString(myData)

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

I was a little curious to know that what is  the difference between using *`as`* keyword , *Casting* or using *`Convert.To_______()`* function.

I after little searching i have found that the *`as`* operator only performs reference conversions and boxing conversions. What other differences are there.

I have also noticed that *`as`* keyword is very rarely used why is it so. Does any one of them has a performance benefit over other or are they just Redundancy in the Framework.

Comment: I happen to see `as` more than `Convert`.

Comment: well considering your reputation  i am sure you have seen more than i have seen, i totally honor your opinion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (cast) syntax is very overloaded, and can perform:

- boxing/unboxing
- reference-preserving type casts
- conversion operators defined on the types
- inbuilt primitive conversions
- Nullable-of-T wrapping/unwrapping

"as" performs a subset of these

- reference-preserving type casts
- some limited boxing of nullable-of-T

But the important feature here is that it doubles as an exception-free **test** of a type relationship - more efficient than having an exception or testing with reflection. In particular, for example:

```
// is it a list?
IList list = obj as IList
if(list != null) {
    // specific code for lists
}
```

If you strongly believe that an object **is** something, a (cast) is preferred as this acts as an assertion of your belief. An exception (in that case) would be desirable.

The Convert methods handle a different range of scenarios including string conversions (otherwise available via things like static .Parse methods)

If anything, it is Convert that I use least. The (cast) and "as" syntax is in very regular use.

Answer (score 1):

casting vs as: casting throws in exception, as returns null if the conversion cannot be made. No performance difference whatsoever.

Convert: entirely different. You can't cast a number to a string, but you can convert is. Read the docs on what the Convert class is capable of.

Answer (score 1):

If you are %100 sure that the object you want to cast will be casted, use Convert,

If not use as.